# Extract array element from couchbase query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I need to make a N1QL query to extract the animal with highest age, from example from here:

```
[
  {
    "animals": [
      {
        "name": "dog1",
        "registered": "7-16-2017",
        "age_in_months": "24",
      },
      {
        "name": "dog2",
        "registered": "7-18-2017",
        "age_in_months": "28",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would need this result:

```
[
  {
    "oldest": 
      {
        "name": "dog2",
        "registered": "7-18-2017",
        "age_in_months": "28",
      }
  }
]
```

I am using this query

```
select t1.animals from `bucket` t1 use keys "myKey";
```

But I have no idea how to extract just part from an array

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Extract the nested animal information using `UNNEST`,
2. Find the animal with the maximum age using `MAX`, and
3. Take another pass over the animals and find the one with the maximum age using a subquery

Steps 1 and 2 are achieved with this query

```
SELECT RAW MAX(animals.age_in_months) 
    FROM `bucket` USE KEYS "myKey" UNNEST animals
```

Step 3 uses `UNNEST` again, but this time we use the output of the previous query to select those animals with the maximum age. This approach will pick all animals with the maximum age.

Here's the complete query:

```
SELECT animal 
  FROM `bucket` b USE KEYS "myKey" UNNEST animals animal 
    WHERE animal.age_in_months IN 
      (SELECT RAW MAX(animals.age_in_months) 
        FROM `bucket` USE KEYS "myKey" UNNEST animals);
```

And here's the result for your example:

```
[
  {
    "animal": {
      "age_in_months": "28",
      "name": "dog2",
      "registered": "7-18-2017"
    }
  }
]
```